# Control audio outside app in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

I'm trying to control my audio player from outside of the app,
I started an av audio session but it's not playing on the background(worked fine on swift 3),

```
        do{


        myPlayer =  AVPlayer(url: url!)

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
            )
            do {
                try audioSession.setActive(true)

            }

        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

my main goal is to control play and pause like this: 
[image]

Comment: Use `MPRemoteCommandCenter`.  Compare: [Play/Pause next/Prev buttons are greyed out in control center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33013383/2415822)

Answer (score 34):

So you are building an app that plays audio on the background using `AVPlayer`. You should use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` to display the song's metadata on the Lock Screen and Control Center, and use `MPRemoteCommandCenter` to control the previous/next/play/pause actions on the lock screen and control center.

- Enable Background Mode for **Audio, AirPlay and Picture in
  Picture** in your **Target > Capabilities**.
- If you're streaming audio from the web, enable Background Mode for **Background Fetch** too.

[image: Background Mode for Audio]

- Import `AVKit` and `MediaPlayer` dependencies.

Setup your `AVPlayer` with an `AVPlayerItem`:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://your.website.com/playlist.m3u8") else {
    return
}
player = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

Setup your `AVAudioSession`:

```
private func setupAVAudioSession() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        debugPrint("AVAudioSession is Active and Category Playback is set")
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        setupCommandCenter()
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Setup the `InfoCenter` and the `RemoteCommandCenter`:

```
private func setupCommandCenter() {
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Your App Name"]

    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [weak self] (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        self?.player.play()
        return .success
    }
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [weak self] (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        self?.player.pause()
        return .success
    }
}
```

You can place the `setupAVAudioSession()` method in your `viewDidLoad()` method, or in any other place you need it.

If you need to place more info in the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` here's a list of all available properties: [General Media Item Property Keys | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/general_media_item_property_keys)

Comment: I don't know why this answer doesn't have more upvotes. Very helpful information. Thanks a lot!